# Clickonce "The application is improperly formatted" when changing COM reference "Isolated" property

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

Using ClickOnce for the deployment of my application.

Publishing the app via ClickOnce works fine, as long as I am deploying to a development machine.  When I deploy to a non-development machine (missing some DLL's and registrations), I get a COM reference error.

So, to solve the COM issue, when I make this one change to my application, ClickOnce fails even more spectacularly:

On one COM reference, if I change the Isolated property from false to true...

- ClickOnce publishes just fine
- Launching the app shows this error: *"Cannot continue.  The application is improperly formatted."*
- If I click "Details..." on the error I see: *"The 'threadingModel' attribute is invalid - The value 'apartment' is invalid according to its datatype 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1:ThreadingModelType' - The Enumeration constraint failed.*"

After some Googling, it seems that the problem may be a character case issue!  I tried changing "apartment" to "Apartment" in the manifest, which I believe may solve the issue, but then I get another error stating that the computed hash on the manifest doesn't match the expected hash (obviously because I modified the manifest).

My questions:

- First, how can I ensure that ClickOnce creates properly formed manifests without this case issue (if this is the problem all together)? Can this be avoided?
- Secondly, if I have to live with this issue, how can I modify the manifests after publishing?
- Third, are there ways of solving this COM registration issue for ClickOnce without modifying the Isolated property?
- Fourth, do you suspect I am doing something strange / out of the ordinary with respect to threading that causes this issue?

Comment: In case it helps: "The COM Reference error" that I mention above is "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {....a guid...} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered" ... (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)

Comment: Any ideas folks!? I did discover a workaround (that I'm not thrilled with): creating my own Prerequisite using the [Bootstrapper Manifest Generator](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg) and installing and registering the COM objects the regular way.  This, of course, adds an extra click and spawns off an additional install process.

Comment: This error is probably due to wrong version of .NET framework installed on the client computer, I had this exact same issue, my build was targeting .NET framework 4.5 while the Windows had 3.5 installed. After I installed .NET framework 4.5 the installation proceeded normally.